# Why is my interface containing a pointer not updating after the pointer is updated?

Tags: go, pointers, memory, memory-management, memory-address

I have a lot of constraints in the issue I am encountering, so I have greatly simplified it to this unnatural code containing the following stuff:

- A struct named `Rect`
- `rA` and `rB` both of which point to a new `Rect` object
- `r1` and `r2`, which are `interfaces` containing `rA` and `rB`
- `r1Adr` and `r2Adr`, which are `interfaces` containing the addresses of `rA` and `rB`

I want to do `rA = rB` without being allowed to reference `rA` or `rB` after declaring my variables.

*(Note: you would think it would be easy, and that you would just do `*r1.(*Rect) = *r2.(*Rect)`.  However, the issue with this approach is that it does not point `rA` to `rB`'s Rect object—it merely clones the values of `rB`'s Rect to `rA`'s Rect.  So, I instead have to dereference a pointer to `rA` (`r1Adr`) and assign it to `rB` so that `rA` points to the same Rect object as `rB`.)*

Below is my attempt at doing so:

```
type Rect struct {
    width int
}

func main() {
    rA := new(Rect)
    rB := new(Rect)

    var r1, r2, r1Adr, r2Adr any
    r1 = rA
    r2 = rB
    r1Adr = &rA
    r2Adr = &rB

    *r1Adr.(**Rect) = *r2Adr.(**Rect)

    // print the address of each Rect object being stored
    fmt.Printf("%p, %p, %p, %p, %p, %p", rA, rB, r1, r2, *r1Adr.(**Rect), *r2Adr.(**Rect))
}
```

`0xc00001c038, 0xc00001c038, 0xc00001c030, 0xc00001c038, 0xc00001c038, 0xc00001c038`

**PLAYGROUND: https://go.dev/play/p/VnQwx6V7DNa**

As you can see from the output, `rA` is correctly updating to `rB`, and `r1Adr` and `r2Adr` are reflecting this perfectly.  However, `r1`'s `rA` is not updating to `rB`, which we know because its output is different.  Why is this?  If `rA` is being updated to `rB`, and if `r1` stores `rA`, then how is it that the `rA` pointed to by `r1` is not updating to `rB`?

Any insight as to how I can initialize `r1` in such a way (without changing it from an interface) that it properly updates after doing `*r1Adr.(**Rect) = *r2Adr.(**Rect)` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"`r1` and `r2`, which are `interfaces` containing `rA` and `rB`"_ - there is nothing in your code that makes `r1` and `rA` (and `r2` and `rB`) special in any way: they're all pointers to their new `Rect` structs, there's no use of `interface` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rA` and `rB` are two pointers pointing to separate objects, `A` and `B`.

`r1` is an interface pointing to `A`, and `r2` is an interface pointing to `B`.

`r1Addr` is an interface pointing to `&rA`, and `r2Addr` is an interface pointing to `&rB`.

Thus, when you update the contents of `r1Addr1`, you point `rA` to `rB`.

However, `r1` and `r2` are still pointing to `A` and `B`; they did not change.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.  I had erroneously assumed r1 is an interface pointing to rA, which points to A.  I am guessing that the answer is no, but just so I can be certain: is it possible to make r1 stay of type *Rect while maintaining that it updates to reflect any changes to rA?  Or is this impossible, and I should just dereference r1Adr in order to make future changes to rA?

Comment: to make changes to rA, you need a **Rect, not *Rect. A *Rect will point to a Rect. A **Rect will point to a variable pointing to a Rect.

Comment: In that case, I will restructure my project such that r1 updates to r1Adr's object every time r1Adr is updated.  Thanks again for the help—you've saved me once again.